# Woocommerce Filter Main Loop by Tag

Tags: shortcode, tags, woocommerce-offtopic

**Two questions:**

1. How can I modify the query results of the archive and search pages exclude the product-tag "audio"?
2. How can I make the Recent Products shortcode of Woocommerce exclude the product-tag "audio"?

*I've created my another shortcode that will display the audio products separately.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Question:** Solved by copying and modifying the "archive-product.php" template file.

```
if(is_product_tag(array('audio'))) :
    include 'archive-product-audio.php'; // includes custom loop
else:
    // default archive loop
endif;
```

**Second Question:** Solved by simply filtering the Recent Products shortcode via "function.php".

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'removeAudioTags');
    function removeAudioTags($args){
        $args['tax_query'] =  array(array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 
            'field' => 'slug', 
            'terms' => array('audio'),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN' 
    ));
    return $args;
}
```